# ffmpeg: Низкая скорость отправки на RTMP

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg, twitch, live

Здраствуйте, появилась задача, необходимо транслировать уже записанные видео 24/7 на платформу Twitch
Я наткнулся на ffmpeg, и он справляется с задачей, но видео постоянно зависает, подгружается, сервер не плохой, 2гб оперативы, 2 ядра, 800р в месяц
Вот мой скрипт запуска

```
#!/bin/bash
server='rtmp://hel03.contribute.live-video.net/app' #Сервер вещания Twitch (https://stream.twitch.tv/ingests/)
key='live_XXXXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' #Ключ вещания
rtmp="$server/$key"

OUTRES="1280x720" #Разрешение
FPS="60"
BITRATE="2500k"
PRESET_LIBX264="ultrafast" #Скорость обработки libx256

function stream() {
        echo "Starting video $1"
        ffmpeg -i $1 -s $OUTRES -c:v libx264 -preset $PRESET_LIBX264 -r $FPS -b:v $BITRATE -b:a $BITRATE -minrate $BITRATE -maxrate $BITRATE -bufsize $BITRATE -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv $rtmp
}

# Запуск стрима
#stream видеофайл
stream video.mp4
stream video2.mp4


#Запуск скрипта заново
bash ./start.sh
```

Но стрим постоянно подвисает, как я понял это связанно с тем что ffmpeg просто не успевает обработать и отправить куски видео.

Как можно облегчить данный код?
На данный момент стрим идёт тут: https://www.twitch.tv/bloodydol
Постоянно подвисает, делаю для знакомого, т.к твич 28 числа отключает возможность повторов.

Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Если что могу предоставить дополнительные данные о сервере, о том как запускаю, или какие-нибуть скрины

Comment: ¿Если видео уже записанное, то зачем его еще перекодировать? Естественно, что 2 ядра недостаточно для x264. Ну и 800р в месяц за такое - просто грабеж.

Comment: А что посоветуете? Избавиться от x264?
Просто очень странно, если я избавлюсь от x264 то он сразу же скорость урезает ещё в несколько раз, если верить выводу ffmpeg
speed падает с 0.9 до 0.3-0.4
Да и maxrate и minrate работать перестают

Comment: Это очень странно. Стриминг - это по сути просто чтение файла с диска и отправка в сеть. maxrate и minrate там вообще не должны фигурировать, изменение битрейта же будет означать перекодирование.

Comment: А два ядра за 800р, это самое дешёвое что нашёл, на том-же регру vds с такими-же характеристиками уже 900р

Comment: @user7860670, да, это просто чтение и отправка, но почему-то не просто)
Уже второй день бью голову над этим